# Как получить доступ к объекту из QAbstractItemModel древовидной структуры?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Имеется класс Chat, который наследуется от QAbstractItemModel.
По сути на выходе я хотел бы получить древовидную структуру, чтоб я мог её вывести в TreeView в qml. Но переопределить метод:

```cpp
//QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
```

невозможно чтобы он возвращал каждый мой элемент дерева как (ChatItem*), а не QVariant. И я смог обращаться с каждым таким item'ом как с объектом. Вызывая Q_INVOKABLE и Q_PROPERTY из ChatItem, когда он выводится TreeView в qml. Например:

```
TreeView{
model : chatModel 
rowDelegate : Item{
    Text { 
      text : model.modelData.text("myCategory") //Q_INVOKABLE
      color: model.modelData.color //Q_PROPERTY из 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Метод `data` должен возвращать именно `QVariant`, а не `ChatItem*`. Для древовидных структур класс `QModelIndex` имеет поле `parent`. И не `Q_INVORKABLE`, а `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Comment: Дык, и как всё таки выводить элементы дерева, чтобы можно было с каждым из них обращаться как с объектом. Я конечно могу написать метод получения отдельного элемента через Index, а потом уже запрашивать объект. Но может быть есть способ не изобретать костыли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно осуществить получение необходимых данных с помощью ролей, для этого необходимо:

- Определить в модели перечисление:

  ```
  enum Roles {
     FIELD1 = Qt::UserRole + 1, 
     FIELD2
  };
  ```
- Переопределить в модели метод roleNames:

  ```
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
      QHash<int, QByteArray> roles = QAbstractListModel::roleNames();
      roles[FIELD1] = "field1";
      roles[FIELD2] = "field2";
      return roles;
  }
  ```
- Модифицировать метод data:

  ```
  QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
  {
      if(!index.isValid())
      {
          return QVariant();
      }

      const ChatItem& item = data_list[index.row()];

      switch (role)
      {
      case Roles::FIELD1: return item.getSomeValue(); // Тут указываете свои методы и свойства из ChatItem
      case Roles::FIELD2: return item.getSomeProperty; //
      default:            return QVariant();
      }
  }
  ```
- Пример использования:

  ```
  TreeView{
    model : chatModel 
    rowDelegate : Item{
      Text { 
        text : model.field1 // Получаем данные с помощью ролей
        color: model.field2
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Неплохая идея, примем её в качестве зачёта, но опять же ::data будет возвращать QVariant...
В данном случае, можно тогда в блоке switch (role) повесить бизнес логику на уровне С++
Я придумал, чуть раньше способ получать модель по индексу через model.getItem(model.index) и уже на месте производить манипуляции. Просто для меня в корне странно, что не предусмотрели для ::data вариант когда он возвращает QObject, а не QVariant

Comment: Предлагаю вам также почитать про преобразование QVariant в собственные типы и наоборот, для этого существует qvariant_cast. Чтобы юзать эту фичу нужно зарегистрировать свой класс с помощью Q_DECLARE_METATYPE. Возможно тоже поможет

Comment: Я хорошо знаком с данной фичей Q_DECLARE_METATYPE. Просто раньше не задумывался, над тем, что возможно когда-то придется строить деревья и внутри каждого Item'a невозможно получить объект, a только данные в виде QVariant. Где мне это нужно: внутри такого объекта дерева(Item'a) хотелось бы через Q_PROPERTY доставать другие QObject. Например если вывожу список пользователей, который в свою очередь может содержать и данные (name, avatar, e.t.c) и структуры отличные обычных полей, например тоже самое дерево связей с другими пользователями. Пример Item->User->Groups->Data, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В Qt'шных примерах есть небольшая программа `simpletreemodel`, в ней для доступа к внутренней структуре элемента дерева используется метод `internalPointer` из `QModelIndex`:

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());

    return item->data(index.column());
}
```

При этом нужно еще переопределить абстрактный метод класса `QAbstractItemModel`:

```
virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const  = 0;
```

в котором нужно вызывать

```
inline QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(int arow, int acolumn, quintptr aid) const
```

для инициализации указателя на Ваш `item`.

Еще есть на мой взгляд очень хорошая модель отображения `JSON` файлов: [`QJsonModel`](https://github.com/dridk/QJsonModel).

Comment: Это я освоил. Излазил вдоль и поперёк всё в этом примере. Но мне надо обращаться к каждому item'у по сути через modelData в qml, а эта модель(QAbstractItemModel) не позволяет мне получить именно объект, как например из Q_PROPERTY(QList<Chat*> items MEMBER m_items CONSTANT). Здесь я прекрасно получаю в qml список, где элементы в qml представлены объектом Chat из которого я могу тянуть методы и свойства.
Я знаю решение, где по индексу передаваемому в qml я могу запросить нужный объект, но это мне кажется неправильным. Должен быть способ представить дерево объектов, а не дерево QVariant данных

Comment: Для чего Вам нужно дерево объектов, как задачу решаете? Может быть зная задачу, я смогу найти решение. Вы не должны использовать QAbstractItemModel::data в коде, этот метод вызывается автоматически. Вы можете создать свой метод и вызывать его. Только тогда зачем вообще в этой задаче использовать модель?

Comment: Древовидную структуру я собираюсь использовать для вывода задач. Каждая задача может быть вложена в другую. И при этом собираюсь организовать Drag&Drop перетаскивание. Кроме этого задачи по сути интерактивные, которые содержат другие объекты(пользователь, статус - зависимый от типа, и т.д.).В общем было бы не плохо обратиться к ней как к объекту, чтобы получать нужные мне вложенные в неё объекты, а не городить огород из JSON + JS. Я хочу организовать доступ из С++ по ссылкам, чтобы не загружать память лишними повторениями.

Comment: Может быть лучше сделать так: model.item(index) ???

Comment: Чем плохо static_cast<Item*> (model->index(row, column).internalPointer()) ? Или в QML так нельзя? Извините, я больше по плюсам могу подсказать.